# Mutate/ifelse conditions with dates to return a numeric object

Tags: r, date, if-statement, mutate

In R: Trying to create a new column that indicates numerically whether another column containing dates has met time period criteria.  The code runs, but it doesn't return correct values (ie, each entry is returned in the new column as 1, when only half of those entries met the "1" condition.

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(g = ifelse(Program.Start.Date >= 2023-08-03 | Program.Start.Date <= 2023-11-30, 1, 
                    ifelse(Program.Start.Date <= 2023-08-03 | Program.Start.Date>= 2023-11-30, 0)))
```

I also tried:

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(g = ifelse(Program.Start.Date >= 2023-08-03 | Program.Start.Date <= 2023-11-30, 1, 0))
```

All rows in the new column G return "1".  I also converted the column "Program.Start.Date" to Year Month Date format using Lubridate.

Comment: Please add a tag for the used programming language.

Comment: If Program.Start.Date is character, you should compare to "2023-08-03". If it's date (preferable), you should compare to `as.Date("2023-08-03")`. As is, you are comparing to 2012 = 2023 - 8 - 3.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What is the class of your Program.Start.Date column? R doesn't have native Date literals like that. if you type `2023-08-03` that just does subtraction and equals `2012` which is likely not what you want.

Comment: @JonSpring does making a `Date` vs `Date` instead of `Date` vs `character` comparison change anything? I've never bothered.

Comment: @GregorThomas - makes no difference, the character is coerced to date so long as it is in the right default format. See `?Ops.Date` - "*Character vectors are converted by 'as.Date'.*"

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, I did not realize the coercion happened that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are at issue:

1. You are not quoting your date values inside your `ifelse()` statement, so R is treating them as an arithmetic equation
2. `|` means 'or' in R, I think you mean `&`. In your code, all dates will equal `TRUE`. Try this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(Program.Start.Date = seq(ymd("2023-08-01"), 
                                          ymd("2023-11-30"), 
                                          by = "day"))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(g = ifelse(Program.Start.Date >= "2023-08-03" & 
                      Program.Start.Date <= "2023-11-30", 1, 0))

head(df)
  Program.Start.Date g
1         2023-08-01 0
2         2023-08-02 0
3         2023-08-03 1
4         2023-08-04 1
5         2023-08-05 1
6         2023-08-06 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @L Tyrone, this did the trick.  I'm new to wrangling in R, so just trying to figure out these nuances.

Comment: The `ymd()` doesn't matter--all that matters is that the comparison dates are quoted so they are not treated as numbers that are subtracted. `ifelse(Program.Start.Date >= "2023-08-03" & Program.Start.Date <= "2023-11-30", 1, 0))` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas. Updated answer accordingly.